# ps --sort: List process active for more than 24 hours

Tags: text-processing, rhel, ps

The command `ps -ef | grep frmweb` gives a huge list for me, which I want to filter:

```
weblogic   687 80703  0 08:58 ?        00:00:03 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,
weblogic  2129 80703  0 06:52 ?        00:00:51 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,
weblogic  2271 80703  0 Apr08 ?        00:00:02 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,
weblogic  2472 80703  0 06:52 ?        00:00:00 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,
weblogic  3997 80703  0 Apr08 ?        00:00:22 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,
weblogic  4504 80703  0 06:53 ?        00:00:01 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,
weblogic  5513 80703  0 09:24 ?        00:00:00 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,
weblogic  7147 80703  0 Apr08 ?        00:00:00 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,
weblogic 10787 80703  0 Apr08 ?        00:02:16 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,
weblogic 12076 80703  0 07:33 ?        00:00:01 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,
weblogic 12857 80703  0 Apr08 ?        00:00:44 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,
weblogic 15078 80703  0 07:35 ?        00:00:02 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,
weblogic 16500 80703  0 Apr08 ?        00:00:00 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,
weblogic 18923 80703  0 Apr08 ?        00:00:01 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,
weblogic 20457 80703  0 Apr08 ?        00:00:20 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,
weblogic 22740 80703  0 10:03 ?        00:00:00 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,
weblogic 23937 80703  0 Apr08 ?        00:00:00 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,simastrosay
weblogic 24175 80703  0 07:03 ?        00:00:00 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,simasystady
weblogic 24242 80703  0 07:40 ?        00:00:04 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,mcskaray
weblogic 24468 80703  0 Apr08 ?        00:00:00 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,mmtrosay
weblogic 24476 80703  0 Apr08 ?        00:00:17 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,mmtrosay
```

I need to get only the processes which are active for more than 24 hours, from the above set.

I have tried `ps -ef --sort` options, but I couldn't get the exact command.

Required output is shown below:

```
weblogic  2271 80703  0 Apr08 ?        00:00:02 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,
weblogic  3997 80703  0 Apr08 ?        00:00:22 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,
weblogic  7147 80703  0 Apr08 ?        00:00:00 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,
weblogic 10787 80703  0 Apr08 ?        00:02:16 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,
weblogic 12857 80703  0 Apr08 ?        00:00:44 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,
weblogic 16500 80703  0 Apr08 ?        00:00:00 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,
weblogic 18923 80703  0 Apr08 ?        00:00:01 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,
weblogic 20457 80703  0 Apr08 ?        00:00:20 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,
weblogic 23937 80703  0 Apr08 ?        00:00:00 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,simastrosay
weblogic 24468 80703  0 Apr08 ?        00:00:00 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,mmtrosay
weblogic 24476 80703  0 Apr08 ?        00:00:17 /opt/weblogic/product/fmw/bin/frmweb webfile=HTTP-0,mmtrosay
```

I need the exact command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like to filter only lines which do not have in column 5 hour:minute (this mean they are older than 24 h)

```
ps -ef | grep frmweb|awk '$5 !~ ":" {print}'
```

As suggested in comment grep can be omitted

```
 ps -ef | awk '/frmweb/ && $5 !~ ":" {print}'
```

Comment: you could also incorporate the `grep` in the `awk`, if you wanted: `awk '/frmweb/ && $5 !~ ":" ...`

Comment: This command is giving the output based on the column we are selecting with the pattern. but I needed the process which are more than 24 hrs or 1 day.

Comment: @ravi, i do not get your point

Answer (score 1):

```
ps -eo bsdstart,pid,cmd | grep frmweb | grep -v '^[ 0-9]'
```

Is giving the exact result.